# Overload C++ set insert

Tags: c++, set, operators, overloading

Is it possible to overload the compare operator in a string set so that it defines two elements with edit distance <= 1 as identical?

This is my failed attempt:

```
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int min(int x, int y, int z) 
{
   return min(min(x, y), z);
}

int getEditDist(string& str1, string& str2, int m, int n)
{
    if (str1[m-1] == str2[n-1])
        return getEditDist(str1, str2, m-1, n-1);
    return 1 + min ( getEditDist(str1,  str2, m, n-1),
                     getEditDist(str1,  str2, m-1, n),
                     getEditDist(str1,  str2, m-1, n-1)
        );
}


class editDist
{
public:
    bool operator () (string& str1, string& str2)
        {
            return(getEditDist(str1, str2, str1.length(), str2.length()) <= 1);
        }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    string id1 = "AAA";
    string id2 = "BBB";
    string id3 = "BAB";
    set<string,editDist> my_set;
    //set<string> my_set;
    set<string,editDist>::const_iterator itr;
    //set<string>::const_iterator itr;
    my_set.insert(id1);
    my_set.insert(id2);
    my_set.insert(id3);
    for(itr = my_set.begin();itr != my_set.end();++itr) cout<<*itr<<endl;
    return(0);
}
```

I'm not even sure it's coded correctly since it doesn't compile.

Comment: If it doesn't compile, it's certainly not _coded correctly_. What's the error in particular?

Comment: Watch out with `using namespace std;`. You may find yourself calling `std::min` rather than your `min`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: no it's not possible to do what you want.

Details:

- you can define a comparator for which d(a,b) ≤ 1 ⇒ a ∼ b;
- the only valid comparator, is ∀(a,b), a ∼ b which is very useless;
- however, it is **not** possible to define a comparator for which d(a,b) ≤ 1 ⇔ a ∼ b which is really what you want.

The comparator defines an ordering and classes of equivalence of strings. If you want any two elements with edit distance ≤ 1 in the same equivalence class, this implies that any elements with edit distance ≤ 2 are in the same equivalence class as well. We can continue the reasoning for any possible edit distance so all the strings must be in the same class of equivalence:

```
 struct always_equal_less {
   bool operator()(std::string const& x, std::string const& y) const {
     return false;
   }
 };
```

### More formal explanation

The `Compare` argument of [`std:set<Key,Compare,Allocator>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) must follow the [Compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) concept i.e. it must define a **strict weak ordering relation**. It must have the following properties:

- transitivity, (a ≺ b ∧ b ≺ c) ⇒ a ≺ c;
- irreflexivity, ¬(a ≺ a);
- assymetry, (a ≺ b) ⇒ ¬(b ≺ a);
- transitivity of incomparability (a ∼ b) ∧ (b ∼ c) ⇒ (a ∼ c).

I'm using a ∼ b for ¬(a ≺ b) ∧ ¬(b ≺ a).

Let's suppose we have such a relationship ≺ which has the additional property that for any two elements with the edit distance is lower or equals than 1 are equals: d(a,b) ≤ 1 ⇒ a ∼ b.

We can show that the only relation for which this is true compares all strings as equals: ∀(a,b), a ∼ b:

- Let's take two elements with edit distance 2, d(a,b) = 2. We can find a third element c such as: d(a,c) = 1 and d(c,b) = 1. We have a ∼ c and c ∼ b. The transitivity of incomparability gives: a ∼ b. This means that any two elements with edit distance 2 are considered equal as well: ∀(a,b), d(a,b) = 2, a ~ b.
- You can continue the reasoning for d(x,y)=3, d(x,y)=4. This shows that any given pair of strings must compare as equal.

We get the (useless) relationship ∀(a,b), a ~ b.

It is thus not possible to define a comparator for which d(a,b) ≤ 1 ⇔ a ∼ b.

Comment: beautiful explanation. Somebody didn't skip algebra class.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't compile because of two reasons:

- you call your min function recursively but with too few args
- the arguments to getEditDist and operator() need to be const

Apart from that your recursion in getEditDist will never finish.

I.e. this will compile:

```
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int min3(int x, int y, int z) 
{
   return std::min(std::min(x, y), z);
   // Or just use `std::min({x, y, z})` if you have C++11 available
}

int getEditDist(const std::string& str1, const std::string& str2, int m, int n)
{
    if (str1[m-1] == str2[n-1])
        return getEditDist(str1, str2, m-1, n-1);

    return 1 + min3(
        getEditDist(str1,  str2, m, n-1),
        getEditDist(str1,  str2, m-1, n),
        getEditDist(str1,  str2, m-1, n-1));
}

class editDist
{
public:
    bool operator () (const std::string& str1, const std::string& str2)
    {
        return(getEditDist(str1, str2, str1.length(), str2.length()) <= 1);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    std::string id1 = "AAA";
    std::string id2 = "BBB";
    std::string id3 = "BAB";
    std::set<std::string, editDist> my_set;
    //set<string> my_set;
    std::set<std::string, editDist>::const_iterator itr;
    //set<string>::const_iterator itr;
    my_set.insert(id1);
    my_set.insert(id2);
    my_set.insert(id3);
    for(itr = my_set.begin(); itr != my_set.end(); ++itr)
        std::cout << *itr<< std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

*But* it will give a stack overflow when you run it. You will need to
change `getEditDist` so that it stops.

Comment: Stack overflow only if the program survives `m` or `n` going negative.